# Setting the text of TextView as a child of my ListView, affects other child views text

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in my code which contains `TextView`s as its child, when my `OnItemClickListener` is fired I will receive a view. This view is the one that I clicked from the ListView. From this part, I will cast this view to make it as TextView. Next, I will set a text of this TextView. The problem is, when I scroll my ListView upward/downward some of the ListView's child text are also change. the ListView redraw its child containing the text of other child text. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:** The view I recieved on the OnItemClickListener is somehow the same with other child view. I found this out when I tried to compared the previous view I clicked and the newly clicked view by using equals() method. scrolling the listview redraws its child but sometimes there are child view that are the same with other child view those are not visible in the list.

This is my OnItemClickListener

```
messagesContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(adapter.getItemViewType(i)==ChatAdapter.VOICE_MESSAGE){
                    RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) view;
                    LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) rootView.getChildAt(0);
                    LinearLayout contentWithBackground = (LinearLayout) content.getChildAt(1);
                    LinearLayout voiceContent = (LinearLayout) contentWithBackground.getChildAt(1);
                    TextView voiceMessage = (TextView) voiceContent.getChildAt(0);
                    voiceMessage.setText("Sample Text");
                }
            }
        });
```

This my Adapter

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<QBChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private Context context;
    private static final int TXT_MESSAGE = 0;
    private static final int IMAGE_MESSAGE = 1;
    public static final int VOICE_MESSAGE = 2;
    private DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<QBChatMessage> chatMessages){
        this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
        this.context = context;
        initImageLoaderOptions();
    }

    public void initImageLoaderOptions() {
        displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        if(getItem(position).getProperty("fileUID") == null){
            return TXT_MESSAGE;
        } else {
            if (getItem(position).getProperty("type").equals(QBAttachment.PHOTO_TYPE)) {
                return IMAGE_MESSAGE;
            } else {
                return VOICE_MESSAGE;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(chatMessages!=null){
            return chatMessages.size();
        } else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public QBChatMessage getItem(int position) {
        if(chatMessages!=null){
            return chatMessages.get(position);
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        QBChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
        final LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            if(type == TXT_MESSAGE){
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, null);
            } else if(type == IMAGE_MESSAGE){
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_image, null);
            } else{
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_voice, null);
            }
            holder = createViewHolder(convertView, type, position);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        QBUser currentUser = ChatService.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        boolean isOutgoing = chatMessage.getSenderId() != null && chatMessage.getSenderId().equals(currentUser.getId());
        setAlignment(holder, isOutgoing, type);

        if (chatMessage.getProperty("fullName") != null) {
            holder.txtInfo.setText(chatMessage.getProperty("fullName") + ": " + getTimeText(chatMessage));
        } else {
            holder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage));
        }

        if(type == TXT_MESSAGE){
            holder.txtMessage.setText(chatMessage.getBody());
        } else if (type == IMAGE_MESSAGE){
            Log.i("Loading", "Loading");
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(AttachmentConstants.URL_S3+chatMessage.getProperty("fileUID"), holder.imageMessage, displayImageOptions);
        }

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(AttachmentConstants.URL_FACEBOOK_OPEN+chatMessage.getProperty("social_picture")+ AttachmentConstants.URL_FACEBOOK_CLOSING, holder.socialPhoto, displayImageOptions);

        return convertView;
    }

    private ViewHolder createViewHolder(View v, int type, final int position) {
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.content = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.content);
        holder.contentWithBG = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);
        holder.txtInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        holder.socialPhoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.social_photo);

        if(type == TXT_MESSAGE){
            holder.txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        } else if(type == IMAGE_MESSAGE) {
            holder.imageMessage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageMessage);
        } else{
            holder.voiceMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.voiceMessage);
            holder.voiceSeekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.voiceSeekBar);
            holder.voiceSeekBar.setEnabled(false);
        }
        return holder;
    }

    private String getTimeText(QBChatMessage message) {
        return TimeUtils.millisToLongDHMS(message.getDateSent() * 1000);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtMessage;
        public TextView txtInfo;
        public LinearLayout content;
        public LinearLayout contentWithBG;
        public ImageView socialPhoto;
        public ImageView imageMessage;
        public TextView voiceMessage;
        public SeekBar voiceSeekBar;
    }
}
```

This is list_item_message_voice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/incoming_message_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/social_photo"
                android:layout_width="33.33dp"
                android:layout_height="33.33dp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/voiceContent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Play"
                    android:id="@+id/voiceMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/voiceSeekBar"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do u know id of that textview?

Comment: yes, i also tried finding its id from the voiceContent but still have same results

Comment: @Apurvak still have the same results. i found out that when the listview redraws its child views during scroll, there are equal child view from visible and those who are not visible. thats why setting a text in textview, affects other child views

Answer (score 1):

The text is getting changed because you changing the text in the `TextView` but not in the `chatMessages` list of the adapter.

```
 @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(adapter.getItemViewType(i)==ChatAdapter.VOICE_MESSAGE){
                    //Your code.....
                    voiceMessage.setText("Sample Text");
                   //Update the chat messages in the list.

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
messagesContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) 
     {
       TextView voiceMessage = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
       if(!voiceMessage.getText().toString().equals(""))
       voiceMessage.setText("Sample Text");

      }
});
```

Try replacing this in your Adapter

```
    else 
    {
      if(!holder.txtInfo.getText().toString().equals(""))
      holder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage));
    }
```

Comment: still have the same results

Answer (score 0):

```
if(convertView == null){          
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, null);
}

// You can set the data here...

return covertView;
```

Comment: For this to be a good answer, you should add some explanation to why you choose to solve the problem like this.

Comment: I need to update my textview's text only when the user click an item from the listview. assuming that this would be the answer. i should include the text that i want to set into my chatMessages arraylist. and from the arraylist i will get the text to set on my textview while executing the getView method.